# Wifi Drivers on older Mac

Tags: wifi, release-hera, macintosh

I installed elementary OS 5.1 on a **2011 Mac Mini**.

During the installation process, the installer recognized the wifi card and downloaded updates during the install.  After a re-boot, the wifi was no longer recognized.  I installed the b43 drivers to correct the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

## My question:

*Why did the wifi work during install, but not after?   If there something I could have done to avoid this issue?*

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not yet mac use but after little research I foudn this super answer from [@metakermit](https://askubuntu.com/users/6418/metakermit) in the Ubuntu StackExchange, I think that can help you.

https://askubuntu.com/a/353993/1013655

Apparently you will also have to install the firmware.

By cons I can not tell you exactly why the wifi works during installation and not after, my skill is not hight but may be that this is the Kernel but it is only a assumption